# Check if Jquery .get() JSON Function Worked

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

If have the following code that brings back a JSON array to be used in a banner delivery system. This works fine although there is some data in the system that populates the JSON array that is causing problems. It's an HTML and Javascript string. Is there any way to check if the below function has executed correctly and if not perform a secondary action?

```
$.get('/X2DFSS46CZKAJ8277/AGS2443WFA', function( data ) {
 if (data != null) {
  $('.side-banner').html('<a href="' + data.bannerUrl + '" rev="2G13' + data.relval + '2SA1X2" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img src="' + data.bannerImgUrl + '"></a>');

  if ($('.side-banner-H').length) {
    if (data.secondBannerImgUrl !== '') {
       $('.side-banner-H').html('<a href="' + data.bannerUrl + '" class="advert-skyscraper-landscape" rev="2G13' + data.relval + '2SA1X2" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img src="' + data.secondBannerImgUrl + '"></a>');
    }
  }

 } 
}, "json" );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the jquery help page, as of jquery 1.5 you should be able to do this

```
$.get('/X2DFSS46CZKAJ8277/AGS2443WFA', function(data) {
    if (data != null) {
        $('.side-banner').html('<a href="' + data.bannerUrl + '" rev="2G13' + data.relval + '2SA1X2" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img src="' + data.bannerImgUrl + '"></a>');
        if ($('.side-banner-H').length) {
            if (data.secondBannerImgUrl !== '') {
                $('.side-banner-H').html('<a href="' + data.bannerUrl + '" class="advert-skyscraper-landscape" rev="2G13' + data.relval + '2SA1X2" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img src="' + data.secondBannerImgUrl + '"></a>');
            }
        }
    }
}, "json").fail(function() {
      // fail code goes here
});
```

similar to @dfsq answer, but less rewrite

Answer (score 0):

You can use error callback:

```
$.get('/X2DFSS46CZKAJ8277/AGS2443WFA', "json").then(function(data) {

    if (data != null) {

        $('.side-banner').html('<a href="' + data.bannerUrl + '" rev="2G13' + data.relval + '2SA1X2" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img src="' + data.bannerImgUrl + '"></a>');

        if ($('.side-banner-H').length) {
            if (data.secondBannerImgUrl !== '') {
                $('.side-banner-H').html('<a href="' + data.bannerUrl + '" class="advert-skyscraper-landscape" rev="2G13' + data.relval + '2SA1X2" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img src="' + data.secondBannerImgUrl + '"></a>');
            }
        }
    }

}, function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log('Error', errorThrown);
});
```